# Issue with promise: ReferenceError: reject is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am working with some own built promise examples to understand how this function is working.

That following code produces the error

> ReferenceError: reject is not defined

I start this with node Promise.js and use node version 8.11.3

Here is my code, the part which produces the error is commented with "problem

```
function testPromise () {

//part 1
  function checkCountOnServer () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var available = false
      if (available) {
        resolve('available')
      }
      else {
        reject('not available')
      }
    })
  }

  function checkPayment () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var booleanTest = true
      if (booleanTest) {
        resolve('payment done')
      }
      else {
        reject('no payment received')
      }
    })
  }

  var checkCountOnServerVar = checkCountOnServer()
  checkCountOnServerVar.then(function (resolve) {
    console.log(resolve)
    return resolve(checkPayment())
  }, function (reason) {
    console.log(reason) //works
    reject(reason) // problem
  }).then(function (value) { console.log(value) },
    function (rejected) {
      console.log(rejected) //problem
    })

}

testPromise()
```

I actually expect the message 'not available' two times.

Even if I change reject(reason) to reject('test') I get the same error.

Help me please.

Comment: At the line marked with `// problem`. `reject` is not in the scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 checkCountOnServerVar.then(function (resolve) {
```

The `then` callback is called with whatever value the promise was resolved to, which is `"payment done"` in your case,and that is not a function, so you can't call it. To chain a promise from inside a then handler, just return it:

```
checkCountOnServerVar.then(function (status) {
 console.log(status);
 return checkPayment();
})
```

Additionally your error catcher does not make sense at all,

```
function (reason) {
  console.log(reason) //works
  reject(reason) // problem
}
```

As `reject` is not defined, and as you actually don't handle the error. If you don't handle the error, there is no sense in attaching a handler, otherwise you should `return` a value the chain can continue with, such as:

```
function(error) {
  console.error("Something bad happened", error);
  return "An error occured, but we don't mind...";
}
```

To sum up:

```
checkCountOnServer()
  .then(serverCount => checkPayment())
  .then(payment => console.log(payment))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: @annaKlein glad to help :)